# glDrawArrays() gives me an exception

Tags: c++, exception, opengl, game-engine

I get this at ***glDrawArrays():***

> " Exception thrown at 0x69A3E360 (nvoglv32.dll) in Test.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000. "

I'm a bit new to modern **OpenGL** and i got this issue when i tried to make a model class. I don't think it has something to do with opengl's version

```
OpenGL Version: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 388.13
GLEW Version: 2.1.0
```

## raw_model.cpp

```
#include "Headers/raw_model.h"

RawModel::RawModel(unsigned int vertexCount, unsigned int vaoID)
{
    this->vaoID = vaoID;
    this->vertexCount = vertexCount;
}

int RawModel::getVaoID() const {

    return vaoID;
}

int RawModel::getVertexCount() const {

        return vertexCount;
}

RawModel::RawModel(){}
```

## renderer.cpp

```
void Renderer::clear()
{
    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.8f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

void Renderer::render(RawModel model)
{
     glBindVertexArray(model.getVaoID());
     glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

     glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, model.getVertexCount()); // Error
     glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
     glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

## loader.cpp

```
#include "Headers/loader.h"

GLuint Loader::createVao()
{   
    GLuint vaoID;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoID);

    vaos.push_back(vaoID);
    glBindVertexArray(vaoID);

    return vaoID;
}

void Loader::storeInAttributeList(int attribNum, float data[])
{
    GLuint vboID;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vboID);

    vbos.push_back(vboID);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(data), data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(attribNum, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

}

void Loader::unbindVao()
{
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

RawModel Loader::loadToVao(float vertices[])
{
    GLuint vaoID = createVao();
    storeInAttributeList(0, vertices);
    unbindVao();

    return RawModel(vaoID, (sizeof(vertices[0])) / 3);
}

void Loader::cleanUp()
{
   for (auto vao : vaos) {

        glDeleteVertexArrays(sizeof(vao), &vao);

    }

    for (auto vbo : vbos) {

         glDeleteBuffers(sizeof(vbo), &vbo);

    }
}
```

Comment: `glDeleteBuffers(sizeof(vbo), &vbo);` Nope. The first parameter is the amount of VBOs in the array, you should probably use `1`.

Comment: RawModel constructor expects vertex count first and then the VAO. But you use it the other way round in loadToVao. Also sizeof(vertices [0]) / 3 is most likely not the vertex count.

Comment: Next: sizeof(data) == sizeof(float[]) == sizeof(float*) which is not the size of your data but the size of the pointer to the data.

Comment: Didn't it compile successfully before?

Comment: @BDL Ok then what should i write instead?

Comment: @derhass oh sry, i meant the code runs fine now

Comment: What should you write instead of what? I thought it runs fine now?

Comment: @BDL yeah runs fine now !